# How can I use automation on Ableton Live unit by unit?

Tags: ableton-live, automation

Frequency shifters are sensible beasts. When I grab one little "dot" and push it just one "unit" down, it goes all the way from 0 to -303 Hz, and when I hold down left ctrl, it changes by 15 Hz instead of 1. How can I use automation "unit by unit"? (0, then -1 Hz, then -2 Hz, etc).

[image]

Comment: Does it make a difference in precision if you zoom in vertically? See vertical zoom here: http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/sep06/articles/livetech_0906.htm